# difference between deleting an object with (X) key and the (Delete)

Tags: objects

Im new to blender.

I wanna know, whats the difference between deleting an object with (X) key and the (Delete) key?

Answer (score 5):

Functionally there's no real difference - the end result is the same - your object gets deleted the same either way. **However, if you press the X key, you get a confirmation about whether you want to delete the object first**, whereas hitting the <kbd>Del</kbd> key skips the confirmation and immediately deletes the object.

That's in Object Mode.

In Edit mode, there is no difference whatsoever as both options present a dialogue box asking *how* you want to delete your selection.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to determine what a shortcut key does is to open Preferences, go to the keymap tab, set search to Key-Binding and search.  Of course, keys like <kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Del</kbd> are used a lot, so you have to do some refining to find the actual usage.  You're asking about object deletion, so we would expect to find the shortcuts under object mode, and here they are:

First the delete key:

[image: Delete Key map entry for Object Mode]

Note that this calls the function `object.delete`.

Next the x key:

[image: X key map entry for Object Mode]

It too calls `object.delete`.  But there's a small difference:  'Confirm' is enabled.

So, the answer is "They both call the delete function on the object, but x has the 'confirm' option set, so it results in a confirm dialog box popping up.